# How to align linear layouts in relative layout by programatically in android

Tags: android

```
|--------------------|--> Relative Layout
|Horizontal linear 1 |
|Horizontal linear 2 |
|Horizontal linear 3 |
|--------------------|
```

in this way.

i want to create one lay out like new contact in android phone.when we press + symbol it will add text box and one remove button dynamically.Please answer this. or any other way to get this format... thank u friends :)

i tried this.

```
 ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        EditText ed = new EditText(this);
        Button bob = new Button(this);
        tv.setText("NextVal");
        ed.setHint("Number");
        ed.setId(++i);
        ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        bob.setText("Rem");
        bob.setId(i);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        allet.add(ed);
        ll.addView(tv);
        ll.addView(ed);
        ll.addView(bob);
        ll.setId(i);
        allli.add(ll);
        rl.addView(ll);
```

Comment: You can use ListView instead of RelativeLayout.

Comment: if you use vertical linear as root layout instead of relative then there is no need of alignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to add LinearLayout params to the linear layout.  You want to add RelativeLayout.LayoutParams because its parent is a RelativeLayout.  Then you can add rules to those params, as @Maxim Efimov suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can set rules by useing [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int,%20int%29) methods.